# Jmeter - Number request are smaller expected

Tags: jmeter, distributed

I run test plan by distributed method in 3 remote machine with config as below:

1. 3 Thread Group: Each 100 users - loop 1
2. Each thread group have 5 request

When i run on each remote machine, i get 500 samples in summary report. But when i run on 3 remote machine in same time, report just display 800 - 1000 samples.

What is problem in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You moT probably have one of the 3 servers that is not reporting the SampleResults to the client.

check jmeter.log of each server.